# Is Collections.syncronizedList effectively a vector?

Tags: java, collections, concurrency

Does `Collections.syncronizedList(new ArrayList())` effectively makes the arrayList a vector? If no then what extra does it do?
If yes then why was it introduced in the first place?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It provides a synchronized view (a wrapper) of any list. The differences:

- you can make a synchronized view of any list implementation. A synchronized `LinkedList` is not a `Vector`.
- the original list is not synchronized - only the view is.

Answer (score 0):

1. It doesn't make a list something else, but wraps a List with something that looks like a list also, but contains no data except the wrapped list.
2. See 1.

Answer (score 0):

`Collections.synchronizedList(...)` wraps synchronized access to the underlying list, but still retains the underlying list's characteristics in other ways. So for example, if you wrap a `LinkedList`, the `iterator()` `remove()` will be an efficient operation. (The same operation on a `Vector` is O(n).)

So the wrapper is absolutely not the same as a `Vector`.